# How to Add Event Handler to Indexed Control in VB6?

Tags: vb6

How to add event handler to index control in VB6

I have indexed control:
txtInput(0), txtInput(1), txtInput(2)

but when i create event to them like **txtInput(0)_Click**, the error showing...
Please tell me how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: And the error (and code) is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add your code to the click event for the control.  Since it's an array, the index for the control being clicked will be an argument on the event handler:

```
Private Sub txtInput_Click(Index as Integer)
  If Index = 0 then
    'code for first control
  ElseIf Index = 1 then
    'code for second control
  Else
    ' and so on ....
  End If
End Sub
```